# When i am running Junit testcases as a bulk object reference from one junit class to another junit class are not setting to null

Tags: java, junit4

I am currently working with Junit4, Object reference are not setting to null when one test class completes execution and started executing another class.It is referencing to old object reference only.I made all object references to null in teardown method too in previous class.Still next test class is pointing to old object reference itself, when i am executing in bulk.I am not able to find the root cause for this.please help me here..Thanks

Comment: post an SSCCE please....

Comment: Can you show us some code please?